Concerning the difference between nodemix and nodematch(with nodefactor) for the R package ergm
I would greatly appreciate your help. I am trying to test whether being under the same chamber of commerce will greatly increase the chance of them forming a network tie and which I have data for 4 chambers for an undirected network. As a beginner, i take reference of the following link
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/471073_d45a4acd780b4987932dc8fc47c46dd5.html
and it seems like both nodemix and nodematch (with the inclusion of nodefactor to address skewed distribution as mentioned in the link) seem to be alternatives for testing the effect of each chamber. However when i test both, there seem to be conflicting result. Assuming i take the nodemix(membership of chambers) approach with Chamber A, B, C and D, which gives me all the combination of A and A, A and B all the way to D and D. The result shows that A > B > C > D with its coefficient. Bu when I apply nodematch(membership of chambers)(with nodefactor(membership of chambers)), it seems to be A > C > B > D.
How should I make sense of it? Great thanks
The nodemix approach actually more aligns with my observation based on the rating of the interviwee (members of each chamber), while nodematch approach confronts, but I will like to have a statisical reasoning about what might be the reason. Great thanks!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
